# select database using mysqli in config.php file

Tags: php, select, mysqli, config

I have a nice free for searching a database.  It was written with PHP and MySql...however for whatever reason, I occasionally need to add an "i" at the end of MySql occasionally to get things working.  I can connect and login, but not select the database, since it passes through until I get the

"request "Unable to select database."

Here's the meat from the config.php file that probably has the issue :

```
$SETTINGS["hostname"]='localhost';
$SETTINGS["mysql_user"]='root';
$SETTINGS["mysql_pass"]='root';
$SETTINGS["mysql_database"]='myDB';
$SETTINGS["data_table"]='data'; // this is the default database name that we used

/* Connect to MySQL */

if (!isset($install) or $install != '1') {
    $connection = mysqli_connect($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"]) or die ('Unable to connect to MySQL server.<br ><br >Please make sure your MySQL login details are correct.');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($SETTINGS["mysql_database"], $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');
};
?>
```

Comment: _I occasionally need to add an "i" at the end of MySql occasionally to get things working_ that is because all `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and are removed in in every version of PHP > 7.

Comment: Update your database select line to `$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $SETTINGS["mysql_database"]) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');`

Comment: You're ignoring some major concerns here. (1) You're using a library you don't understand and found somewhere on the internet. *Don't do that.* (2) You wrote, "for whatever reason, I occasionally need to add an "i" at the end of MySql occasionally to get things working." MySQL and MySQLi are two different libraries, and your comment tells us you didn't know that. You should not be using *any* code that uses the old, deprecated (removed in PHP 7), and insecure MySQL library. *[to be continued]*

Comment: (3) The answer is staring you in the face in the `mysqli_select_db(...)` line. It should be obvious what that does. If it is not obvious, then you really should start with a basic tutorial before doing anything else.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but any code you have written so far is likely extremely insecure and should be thrown out. We're not criticizing you -- we were all beginners once -- but this question is full of red flags.

Comment: I'm glad I made it clear that I'm a complete novice...last thing I wanted was an answer I couldn't understand...I actually do understand the difference between the two, however goal was to get someone to get it to work when I knew it was a little tweak...unfortunately, most of the free scripts out there are coded for MySql...also, although I would love to take more time to learn this from a beginners level, I really don't have that kind of time. thanks for the advice, but I'll use the free scrips at my own risk.  Ed, I do thank you however for answering my question...it did do the trick.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

With `mysqli`, you can select your database directly using the connection method :

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"], $SETTINGS["mysql_database"]);
```

If you want to use `mysqli_select_db`, you need to reverse your arguments. First the connection, then the database :

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, $SETTINGS["mysql_database"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the line in which you select the database;

```
$db = mysqli_select_db($SETTINGS["mysql_database"], $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');
```

As defined by the documentation of [`mysqli_select_db()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) the connection `$connection` (`$link` in the docs) should be the first argument:

```
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $SETTINGS["mysql_database"]);
```

---

The reason why you need to occasionally add an **`i`** to every `mysql_*` function is because all `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](https://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.